# Nop: Error executing child request for handler 'System.Web.Mvc.HttpHandlerUtil+ServerExecuteHttpHandlerAsyncWrapper'

Tags: asp.net-mvc, nopcommerce

I'm trying to write a plugin. I started by testing whether I could display something on the Index page. Here's my code:

```
//My main plugin class
public IList<string> GetWidgetZones()
{
  return new List<string>{ "home_page_before_news" };
}

//My action
[ChildActionOnly]
public ActionResult DisplayLink(string widgetZone, object additionalData = null)
{
   _cacheService.Clear();
   return View("~/Plugins/Widgets.PartnershipManager/Views/DisplayLink.cshtml");
}

//My view
@{ 
   Layout = "";
}

<a href="#">My first link</a>
```

I'm getting the following error: **Error executing child request for handler 'System.Web.Mvc.HttpHandlerUtil+ServerExecuteHttpHandlerAsyncWrapper'.**

With no further information. Yet, I tried to match the code for NivoSlider as much as I can. Am I missing something?

Thanks for helping

## EDIT

Here are **GetConfigurationRoute** and **GetDisplayWidgetRoute** methods:

```
public void GetConfigurationRoute(out string actionName, 
            out string controllerName, 
            out RouteValueDictionary routeValues)
{
   actionName = "Configure";
   controllerName = "PartnershipManager";
   routeValues = new RouteValueDictionary()
   {
     { "Namespaces", "Nop.Plugin.Widget.PartnershipManager.Controllers" },
     { "area", null }
   };
}

 public void GetDisplayWidgetRoute(string widgetZone, 
        out string actionName, out string controllerName, 
        out RouteValueDictionary routeValues)
 {
    actionName = "DisplayLink";
    controllerName = "PartnershipManager";
    routeValues = new RouteValueDictionary()
    {
      { "Namespaces", "Nop.Plugin.Widget.PartnershipManager.Controllers" },
      { "area", null },
      { "widgetZone", widgetZone}
    };
  }
```

This where the error is happening

```
public static MvcHtmlString Widget(this HtmlHelper helper, 
       string widgetZone, object additionalData = null, string area = null)
{
        return helper.Action("WidgetsByZone", "Widget", 
                      new { widgetZone = widgetZone, 
                      additionalData = additionalData, area = area });
}
```

Comment: Why `[ChildActionOnly]` here?

Comment: That's how it's in the other plugin that I'm trying to emulate. Also, this method is being called by an `@Html.Widget("widget zone")` method from the view. I guess that method is kind of a `@Html.Action()`. The output of this method is supposed to be display in a particular zone on the page.

Comment: Did you configure `GetDisplayWidgetRoute` method properly in your main plugin class?

Comment: @Ratul please find in the Edit both `GetConfigurationRoute` and `GetDisplayWidgetRoute` methods

Comment: @Richard77 The methods appear to be OK. I copied your methods, views and my plugin works perfectly. Which version of nop do you use?

Comment: I'm using version 3.80